# Scheme - Secuence of numbers that sum 0 in a list

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to implement a recursive function (sums cero) that given a list of integers, it prints all possible secuences of consecutive numbers that sum up 0

Example 1:

> (sum-zero ‘(4 2 -3 -1 0 4))

=> (-3 -1 0 4)

(0)

Example 2:

> (sum-zero ‘(3 4 -7 3 1 3 1 -4 -2 -2))

=> (3 4 -7)

(4 -7 3)

(-7 3 1 3)

(3 1 -4)

(3 1 3 1 -4 -2 -2)

(3 4 -7 3 1 3 1 -4 -2 -2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function needs to have a helper that has arguments for 1. the list of available numbers, 2. the current numbers, 3. the list of results of combination that sum to zero so far. Here is how I would have done it, with some parts left out to keep us from doing your homework:

```scm
(define (sum-zero lst)
  ;; insert e such that the resulting list i ssorted
  ;; (insert 3 '(1 3 4)) ; ==> (1 3 3 4)
  (define (insert e lst)
    <implement>)

  ;; main logic
  (define (helper lst acc res)
    (if (null? lst)
        res
        (let* ((new-acc (insert (car lst) acc))
               (res (if <should add new-acc to res>
                        (cons new-acc res)
                        res)))
          ;; call the helper skipping the current element in the result
          ;; and use that as the result on the secon call the includes it
          (helper (cdr lst)
                  new-acc                  
                  (helper (cdr lst) acc res)))))

  ;; notice () is already in the results
  (helper lst '() '(())))
```

Testing it is straightforward. I got some more results than you though but I believe it is correct:

```scm
(sum-zero '(3 4 -7 3 1 3 1 -4 -2 -2))
; ==> ((-7 -4 -2 -2 1 1 3 3 3 4)
;      (-7 -4 -2 3 3 3 4)
;      (-7 -2 -2 1 1 3 3 3)
;      (-7 -4 1 1 3 3 3)
;      (-7 -2 3 3 3)
;      (-7 -2 -2 1 3 3 4)
;      (-7 -4 1 3 3 4)
;      (-7 -2 1 1 3 4)
;      (-7 3 4)
;      (-4 -2 1 1 4)
;      (-4 -2 -2 1 3 4)
;      (-2 -2 4)
;      (-4 4)
;      (-7 1 3 3)
;      (-4 -2 -2 1 1 3 3)
;      (-4 -2 3 3)
;      (-2 1 1)
;      (-2 -2 1 3)
;      (-4 1 3)
;      ())
```